# Compare XML and JSON files using the same algorithm

Tags: c#, json, xml, algorithm

**Introduction:** I'm working on a project where I have multiple files which represents a profile(model) for a specific resource(for example a person) in my system. These profiles can be stored as XML and JSON and they are used to validate the specific resource(the person) which is another XML or JSON file. So every file that contains data about a person needs to be validated against a profile which contains constraints that are specific for that person. For example the profile can specify that the person can't have more that two contact options(phone and email).

**Problem:** There are multiple systems that have profiles about a person. If I want to get data about a person from another system I need to get the profile of the person first and check that the constraints from my profile are compatible with the profile from the other system. These profiles are between 500 and 5000 lines each and I don't know if I get an XML or JSON from the other system. So I need to write an algorithm that can compare the profile that I get from the other system with the profile that I have in my system as fast as possible(no matter the format) and if the profiles constraints does not match to give the user some options to choose from.

**Question:** How can I write an algorithm that can find the differences between two profiles and give the user options to merge them if the constraints are not compatible. There are some constraints about the algorithm too:

1. Needs to compute the differences and show the options in a relatively short time. I'm thinking about less than 15-20 seconds if that is possible. Some profiles ar about 5000 lines and there will be checks for the constraints that does not match.
2. The algorithm needs to be written in C# as a class library so every developer can use it in his system.
3. I have read about NoSql databases to be suitable for formats like XML and JSON. So if the time constraints are not achievable with a class library I can make a web app where users can compare profiles and merge them. The app can store the profiles in the NoSQL database and make operations on that, if this a viable solution.
4. There should be a single algorithm to maintain

**What I know so far:** There are libraries like XmlDiff and classes to work with xml files but I also need to compute json files. I know there are classes for json files also but I don't want to write and maintain two class libraries. Should I convert json to xml or vice versa? Should I start to study about NoSQL and how could that help the algorithm?

I need some starting points and ideas if anyone encountered that before or knows about computing xml and json files in an efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find normalized form of one of these formats. I would use JSON, beucase it feels to be less problematic (in XML you can have semantically the same information once written using elements and using attributes). But the choice is yours, there would be a lot of normalization libraries for both.

Now suppose I did this for XML -> JSON

1. doc1 = transformToJson(xml)
2. normalize(doc1) // order fields alphabetically, remove null fields, use quotation marks where necessary, force data types - if schema available
3. normalize(doc2)
4. jsonCompare(doc1, doc2) //in Java I would use something like this (https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch), I suppose there would be the same thing for C#

Other possibility would be to convert both representation to maps (because both formats are effectively maps) and compare the maps.

---

NoSql will not help you, it may just do some of the transformation magic for you...but it would be like using a SQL database for Integer -> Date conversion (because there is a function for that)...